# Display JPanels on top of JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, layout, overlay, jprogressbar

I am trying to display `JLabel`s on top of a `JProgressBar` so that I can have fancy formatted text on a `JProgressBar`.

Here is the constructor for my component, which extends `JPanel`:

```
public InfoDisplay() {
    //setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));

    lblPlayer = new JLabel();
    lblPlayer.setName("Owner");
    lblUnit = new JLabel();
    lblUnit.setName("Unit");
    lblCoords = new JLabel();
    lblCoords.setName("Coordinates");
    lblResources = new JLabel();
    lblResources.setName("Resouces");

    prgProgress = new JProgressBar();
    prgProgress.setMaximum(4);
    prgProgress.setStringPainted(true);

    fmtDefault = "<html><font color='gray'>%s:</font> %s</html>";

    JPanel pnlInfo = new JPanel();
    pnlInfo.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    pnlInfo.setOpaque(false);
    pnlInfo.add(lblPlayer);
    pnlInfo.add(lblUnit);
    pnlInfo.add(lblCoords);
    pnlInfo.add(lblResources);
    add(pnlInfo);
    add(prgProgress);

    displayInfo(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
    setProgress("Upkeep", 2);
}
```

I have tried using `OverlayLayout`, which achieves this goal when the form is created. However, when the `JProgressBar` updates, it covers up the other panel which holds the text fields.

I have also tried using a `JLayeredPane`, but I would have to write a custom layout manager for that to work and I was hoping to avoid doing all of the resizing code by hand for such a simple thing.

Does anyone have any other solutions or ideas?

Comment: Have you tried (with the `OverlayLayout`) adding the progress bar first?

Comment: Yes, and when I did that it covered up the panel full of JLabels immediately instead of waiting for an update. I think the problem is finding a way to keep the JProgressBar on the bottom forever.

Comment: Try adding a repaint() on the main panel after updating the progress bar. Then both components should get repainted at the same time

Comment: Have you tried using [`JProgressBar#setString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setString%28java.lang.String%29) and passing the formatted `String` to it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, you can send a "formatted" string to a JProgressBar but with a JLabel you can use HTML formatted text. A JProgressBar can't handle that, it just shows the raw HTML. I have the default format string up there... It's multicolored and uses bolding and italics. Not super fancy but too fancy for JProgressBar.

Comment: @camickr -- That worked. I was under the impression that layout managers were supposed to handle that stuff on their own... I was wrong apparently. Thank you.

Comment: Layout managers position and size the components, they are not responsible for repainting components.

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach is to just add the panel to the progress bar then you don't have to worry about invoking repaint. The progress bar will automatically repaint its child component:

See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html). I added the following code to the `ProgressBarDemo`:

```
progressBar.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
JPanel child = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
child.setOpaque(false);
child.add( new JLabel("WEST"), BorderLayout.WEST );
child.add( new JLabel("EAST"), BorderLayout.EAST );
progressBar.add(child);
```

Comment: The repaint worked, but adding the components to the JProgressBar causes problems with resizing... the JPanel doesn't understand the bounds of the components inside. When I add the panel, it doesn't repaint its children. The manual call to repaint is the best solution.

Comment: I meant to say, the JProgressBar doesn't understand the bounds of the components inside.

Comment: @scott_fakename, maybe use a different layout manager. The GridBadLayout will collapse the panel to the center unless you use a weightX/Y value. Maybe a BorderLayout is a better choice. See updated example. The point is you can treat the progress bar like a panel. You can even add the components directly to the progress bar without adding them to a panel first.

Comment: Flow and border are what I used in the first place... I usually avoid gridbag in favor of grid, border, and box coupled with sub-panels, but in this case I think that's a red herring. The progress bar didn't resize itself to become wide enough for the labels and required a call to repaint for the jpanel added anyway when I tried it again. Thanks. I think just using overlay and giving it that "repaint()" nudge will do nicely. Not sure where, but I have read in the javadocs that using components that are not "intended" as containers (like panels and frames) can lead to funky behavior. Oh well.

Comment: use JLayer, this methods is about illusion, creates only rendering components over, [some examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A177145+jlayer) by @aterai

Comment: @mKorbel, I thought about JLayer, but the OP's problem is that the size of the top panel is greater than the progress bar. (That is the reason my suggestion doesn't work) By using the overlay layout the progress bar is automatically resized to the size of the top panel.